# Workflow System vs MultiThreading to resolve lambda time out constraints

Tags: multithreading, aws-lambda, workflow, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda which has to call lot of Jobs (All the jobs is to call another lambda) and once all the jobs are completed successfully , I have to send notification to another system that's why I am calling each of them synchronously and sequentially which is causing lambda to time-out.

I have two solutions

1. Use Step Functions or any other workflow system in which once all the jobs reach to their terminal state workflow will know and notify the other system
2. I am calling all the jobs in multi-threaded fashion as all the jobs will be blocked on network I/O so processing is speeding up a lot and I am able to process all the request within constraints

I know this is a classical problem of workflow, Question is why or why should I not use multithreading or step function ?

Can multi-threading leads to unknown issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Step Functions. Using multiple threads is more of a workaround than a solution, because you are just moving the problem you currently have to re-emerge at a later point in time.

Consider the following: a Lambda does have a finite amount of vCPUs. The maximum amount you can get is 6 (at the time of writing).

That means you can not "just" run 10.000 jobs in parallel. There are just not enough cores/CPUs to run all the jobs in parallel. That means you are still more or less running them sequentially, just faster than before.

So there might come a point where you process so many jobs that even with multithreading you are going to run in a timeout. Hence, you are just moving this issue farther in the future, but you are not solving it.

Therefore, I think that using Step Functions is the better solution. Obviously, Step Functions also have limits, but there are easier to handle/manage. And you can actually have more jobs run in parallel than with multithreading.